# Shall I use ROS plugins to make ROS communicate with my Library?

Tags: ros, simulation, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am new to ROS and want to use it to communicate between the nodes of my own library. I want to know whether I shall create plugins to make it communicate with the parts of my library ?
for example https://nengoros.wordpress.com/ is a neural networks simulator and it uses ROS to make it communicate between it's modules(nodes). I am working on something similar but not sure whether I should use ROS plugins.
Any information will be helpful.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258404/shall-i-use-ros-plugins-to-make-ros-communicate-with-my-library-?/) by [saranshvora](https://answers.ros.org/users/29896/saranshvora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understood well what you need to do is having some c++ class that you need to use in your node. If this is the case simply use add_library in your CMakeList.txt to define your library with a name. Then, make sure you like your library to your node using target link libraries command.

If you need to share a C++ library in your environment so other packages can use it as well, u need to export your library.

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0